# Coevaluation for linear categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

For a field $k$ and an associative $k$-algebra $R$, the $k$-linear category $R\operatorname{-Mod}$ is self dual inside $\operatorname{DGCat}_k$, with the counit map sending $k$ to $R$ regarded as a bimodule over itself.

My question is - for a general dualizable DG category $\mathcal{C}$, should we expect the underlying vector space of the image of $k$ under the coevaluation to be an algebra, and if so - what is the relation between modules over this algebra and the original category?

Here’s the intuition I have: In the case of modules there’s a monoidal forgetful functor from bimodules to vector spaces, and the coevaluation has a natural algebra structure coming from the identification with the identity endofunctor. The algebra structure on $\operatorname{coev}(k)$ then should come from combining these two structures. I’m not sure about the precise statement

Comment: What's the "underlying functor" for an arbitrary $C$ ?

Comment: I guess I should've added it as part of the question... If we have a symmetric monoidal category and a fiber functor we'll have reconstruction theorem, so I was wondering if there's a weaker version where you'll still get an algebra but it won't be an equivalence of categories (specifically I have in mind certain subcategories of modules over a Lie algebra, so there's definitely a forgetful functor)

Comment: Well one way to phrase it is that coev always picks out the identity endofunctor of $C$, which is the unit for the composition monoidal structure. Since coev is monoidal, its right adjoint is lax monoidal, and so sends coev(k) to an algebra. In the case of R-modules, this right adjoint is exactly the forgetful functor

Comment: Please explain what a "DG category" and the "reconstruction theorem" are.

Comment: DG category for me is just another name for a $k$-linear $(\infty,1)$ category, maybe not the best terminology... Reconstruction theorem is Tannakian duality that reconstruct a Hopf algebra from its category of representations equipped with a monoidal forgetful functor

Comment: @MaximeRamziI don't think the right adjoint of coev is the forgetful functor. I think what's going on here is that if $A$ is a monad on $C=R-Mod$, aka an algebra in $End(C)=R-Bimod$, then there is in fact an equivalence $A-Mod_{C}\simeq A-Mod_k$ i.e. the underlying $R$-module structure is somehow forced. This is quite special to this situation.